# How to insert the experimental data from the xlsx file into the minimization objective function?

Tags: python, function

I want to find optimal value for the coefficients: a,b,c and d.

How does the experimental data look like?

[image]

How does the mathematical modeling equation look like?

```
def equation(oc, a, b, c, d):
    return np.exp(a) * (np.exp(b*oc[0])) * (np.exp(c*oc[1])) * (np.exp(d*oc[2]))
```

The optimization process should minimize the error for a,b,c and d so that the experimental data can hit the experimental data.

My proposal:

```
x0 = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0] 

# Define the objective function to minimize
def objective(x):
    a, b, c, d = x
    oc = df[['oc1', 'oc2', 'oc3']].values.T
    y_pred = equation(oc, a, b, c, d)
    y_true = df['mean'].values.T
    mse = np.sum((y_pred - y_true) ** 2)
    return mse

# region Minimize the objective function
res = minimize(objective, x0, method='Nelder-Mead')
```

What would be an elegant idea?

Comment: Can you post the sample data in text format rather than image format?

Answer (score 0):

Your model is not good. The following code runs but the fit is poor.

```py
from io import StringIO

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.optimize

with StringIO('''test_no,mean,std,oc1,oc2,oc3
1,0.79137615,0.67077612,95,45.00,0
2,0.11784323,0.9668567,80,47.50,0
3,0.45037581,0.65684495,80,30.00,1
4,0.86343574,0.24830439,90,30.00,1
5,0.29071445,0.21744955,95,30.00,1
6,0.04779846,0.631681,95,45.00,1
7,0.47189424,0.33075422,95,20.00,1
''') as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, index_col='test_no')


def equation(oc: np.ndarray, a: float, *bcd: tuple[float, float, float]):
    return np.exp(a + oc.T.dot(bcd))


popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(
    f=equation,
    xdata=df[['oc1', 'oc2', 'oc3']].values.T,
    ydata=df['mean'],
    p0=(0, 0, 0, 0),
)
print(popt)
```